# Does Apples UI define Drag&Drop in menus and/or context menus for menu items

Tags: cocoa, user-interface, macos

I'm trying to update my GUI a little bit but don't want to run into porting problems later next year when a native Cocoa Port will be started.

On Windows/Linux it is common to drag items out of menus or being able to right click on a menu item and display a context menu for this menu item.

Is there anything like this on MacOSX.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can put a view into a menu item, and you can drag from a view, but I don't know whether those two will work together (i.e., whether you can drag from a view that's in a menu item).

More importantly, this isn't normal on the Mac, so you need another place to drag the item from regardless of whether you can support dragging from the menu or not.